# How to remove scratches from metallographic images using Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the following image to analyze and extract the porosity out of it (black dots).

[image: metallographic image of porous alloy]

My issue is that my code might be picking up on the scratches (defects from polishing the cross-sections).
I am looking for a way to remove the scratches.

I tried Inpainting (https://github.com/Chandrika372/Image-Restoration-by-Inpainting-Algorithm/blob/main/Inpainting.py) but the scratches are too small for detection. I also found few  examples running on C and with Matlab, but if I use my image as an input, the output is still the same; the scratches seem too fine for the algos.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please post a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), showing your best attempt so far and a clear way to judge success?

Comment: that one scratch there leaves enough of a mark to compete with the "blotches" that you seem interested in. *I would not try to remove it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) should do it. The idea is to [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering) to remove noise then [`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) to extract the dots.

Binary image

[image]

Result

[image]

You can also optionally filter out large/small dots using [contour area filtering](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) with a threshold value

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# OPTIONAL to filter out small/large dots using contour area filtering
# Adjust the area to only keep larger dots
'''
DOT_AREA = 10
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < DOT_AREA:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)
'''

# Bitwise_and to extract dots
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=thresh)
result[thresh==0] = 255

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: You say "Gaussian blur to remove noise"... But what removed?

Looking the binarize only (without blur) result with Othu method, almost all "scratch" do not apper.
Some strong (deep?) scratches remain, but they are remaining on your result too.

It seems that the main effect of blurring becomes to kill small black dots (we don't know if it's unnecessary).

Comment: Oh you're right it should say Gaussian blur to smooth and remove detail instead of noise. Blurring combines adjacent pixels together to form a larger blob and reduce detail so that thresholding will remove the scratches

Comment: Of course, if we don't need such small dots that disappear due to blurring, there is nothing wrong.
Therefore it is also thinkable to blur more strongly to remove the remaining scratches.
i.e. the strength of blurring we should use is depend on which size dots are needed, and the "strength 0" that means without blur may be a selectable option (In other words, the case without blurring will be included in this answer, I think).